# Making a dictionary of unique words in constitution with their sentences in Python

Tags: python, iteration, cpu-word

I am trying to make a dictionary of all unique words in the US constitution with the key as the word and the value as the sentence the word is in (this can be multiple sentences)
So I made a list of all unique words, and then I have a list of all sentences, but I am having trouble iterating through both to see if the word exists in the sentence. How do I do this? 
I am using python and am a little past beginner level

Thanks so much

Comment: Can you show us some of your code?

Comment: Yes! here:wordlist=[]
 for word in words:
  if word not in wordlist:
   wordlist.append(word)
 wordlist.sort()

 infile=open("US_Constitution.txt", "r")
 textlist=[]
 for line in infile:
  line=line.rstrip('\n')
  textlist.append(line)
I've already cleaned the words with punctuation & newlines, so here is my code for the word list and my text list(list of sentences)

Comment: @ColetteConway please [edit] the question to include the code

Answer (score 0):

It would be more memory-efficient to store the indices of the sentences in the dictionary, but based on you desired data structure, you could skip the list of words with something like this:

```
word_sentences = {}

for sentence in sentences:
    for word in ' '.split(sentence):
        if not word in word_sentences:
            word_sentences[word] = []

        word_sentences[word].append(sentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it using regex (regular expressions):

```
import re

slist=['a cat','a dog','a yacht','Cats and Dogs']
wlist=['cat','dog']

for aword in wlist:
    w=re.compile(".*(" + aword + ").*", re.IGNORECASE)
    print(aword, [i for i,s in enumerate(slist) for m in [w.search(s)] if m])
```

This will print:

```
cat [0, 3]
dog [1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

That actually sounds like a fun project! I think the best way is to parse through and keep a set of unique sentences at the same time as keeping a cache of unique words. Check the comments in line for an explanation. We remove punctuation to avoid any awkward words with commas.

```
import string
from collections import defaultdict

with open('const.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

word_to_sentence_cache = defaultdict(set) # to make sure we don't repeat sentences with the same word multiple times
for line in data:
    cleaned_line = line.translate(None, string.punctuation) # we ignore commas and such when finding words
    words = cleaned_line.split()
    for word in words:
        word_to_sentence_cache[word].add(line)


def print_sentences_from_constitution_with_word(word_to_sentence_cache, word):
    words = word_to_sentence_cache.get(word, None)
    words = [word.rstrip() for word in words] if words != None else 'Not in Constitution'
    print words
```

print_sentences_from_constitution_with_word(word_to_sentence_cache, 'people')

```
['right of the people to keep and bear Arms, shall not be infringed.', 'The right of the people to be secure in their persons, houses, papers, and', 'of the press; or the right of the people peaceably to assemble, and to petition', 'executive thereof to make temporary appointments until the people fill the', 'State, elected by the people thereof, for six years; and each Senator shall']
```

print_sentences_from_constitution_with_word(word_to_sentence_cache, 'People') # note the capitalization

```
['Year by the People of the several States, and the Electors in each State shall', 'We the People of the United States, in Order to form a more perfect Union,']
```

print_sentences_from_constitution_with_word(word_to_sentence_cache, 'dinosaur')

```
Not in Constitution
```

Here is the reference txt file I used: 
https://www.usconstitution.net/const.txt